Como verifico alcances en un equipo en GCP?
Me encargaron verificar los alcances a bases de datos en un equipo en GCP, como puedo hacer esto?
Por ejemplo, me piden verificar los alcances a la base de datos: 11.22.333.44 30001
Que herramienta o como puedo hacerlo?
Intente en Cloud Shell pero no se si sea lo correcto en si.
